# Select MySQL limit columns by post request with columns number

Tags: php, mysql, post

I am trying to get MySQL columns by send PHP post request to the MySQL with columns number

---

PHP:

```
<?php

$columns = $_POST['number'];     

$result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM table3 order by RAND() LIMIT '$columns'");

?>
```

---

HTML:

```
<form action="file.php" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="number" value="5" autocomplete="off">

    <input type="submit" Value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: And you're getting an error? Is `$columns` an int? Try casting it.

Comment: Take the quotes out. I missed that on first view. Also cast it as an int or escape the user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying

```
SELECT * FROM table3 order by RAND() LIMIT '5'
```

See the quote issue?

It should be

```
<?php
$columns = (int)$_POST['number'];     
$result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM table3 order by RAND() LIMIT $columns");
?>
```